# Dictionary changing many values to many keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I was just wondering if in the wonderful world of Python there is any way to go from something like this:

```
dict1 = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}
```

to

```
dict2 = {'a':1, 'a':2, 'a':3,'b':4, 'b': 5, 'b': 6]
```

or equivalent, the order is irrelevant but I need some way of decomposing dict1 into something in which I can assign the numerical values to indices of a new list and the keys as the actual values of those indices e.g. dict1 would turn into:

```
[0, a, a, a, b, b, b]
```

Any help would be appreciated, although the more idiot proof the answers the better.

I am indebted to you once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `dict2` makes no sense because dictionary keys must be unique.

I am pretty sure you can get what you want by iterating over `dict1.items()`, but I need some more clarification on what the expected output list looks like... in your example `a` and `b` are undefined and I don't know what the `0` at the start is representing.

Perhaps you wanted something like this?

```
dict2 = {}
for k,v in dict1.items():
  for x in v:
    dict2[x] = k
```

This would give you a `dict2` like `{1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}`.  Be warned that duplicate entries in the unpacked values of `dict1` could be overwritten by this loop.

---

Just for shits and giggles, the same thing in 1 line as an ***incomprehensible dict comprehension***:

`{x: k for (k,v) in dict1.items() for x in v}`

Comment: That's what I feared, do you know of anyway of going from dict1 to the list at the end without doing the middle step?

Comment: Yes, you can iterate over `dict1.items()`.. I will update my answer

Comment: To clarify the items in the list will be strings all of which contain one word, also I only included the 0 because I started the numbering dict1 at 1 instead of 0 like an idiot.

Comment: Can’t believe I never tried to do a dict comprehension myself before. I learned something new today, thanks a lot! :o

Comment: I don't suppose someone could quickly tell me how to find the max of something like this? [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 0], [3, 4, 5]] I keep trying to append the items to a new list but it won't work :(

Comment: max(itertools.chain(*your_list))

Comment: I don't think the dict comprehension is 'incomprehensible' at all.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel then you have truly grokked python! i always have to imagine the nested loops and then mentally wrap it up with these double comprehensions..

Comment: Let me be clearer: I don't think "imagining the nested loops" is a meaningful barrier to comprehensibility.

Answer (score 2):

If values represent indices then:

```
import itertools

dict1 = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]}

L = [None]*(max(itertools.chain(*dict1.values())) + 1)
for word, indexes in dict1.items():                          
    for i in indexes:                                     
        L[i] = word
print(L)
# -> [None, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```